# Looping though a while statement

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I have a sequence of mysql query result resources stored in a array.

E.G array([0] => resource [1] => resource ...ect);

This code retrieves the first resource in the array:

```
$third_count = "0";
while ($user_result = mysql_fetch_array($user[$third_count])) {
print_r($user_result);
}
$third_count = $third_count +1;
```

I'm just stuck trying to find an if statement that'll loop though the array.

Something like: while ($third_count =< $second_count) is what I need, but it doesn't seem to work.

Where $second count is the number of elements in the array.

Thanks for pointers!

Comment: Ahh fixed it myself. Got the =< bit the wrong way round. Didn't look right!

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is use a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop to loop through that array of result resources.  Counts will not matter then.

```
foreach($resourcearr as $res) {
    while ($user_result = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
        print_r($user_result);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought of doing it like that, but I wasn't certain result resources (as opposed to normal arrays) could be used like that.

Comment: It is a normal array.  It is just an array of resources.